# Cannot paste into Free Download Manager Program?

Tags: download-manager

I need to copy/paste URL from browser into Free Download Manager. I copy it find but it pastes blank. I opened notepad and pasted there and it pastes fine in there.

What could cause this?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure FDM to be "aware" of a browser (IE, Firefox and others) and also to *automatically* copy the URL in the clipboard. Go to *Options | Settings* and under *Downloads | Monitoring*, enable *Monitor clipboard* and any browser listed that you use.

Comment: Didn't help. Still can't copy paste and it doesn't recognize my clipboard.

Comment: Apparently Webroot anti virus is doing this. Pasting worked when I shut off AV...

Comment: @CoryNickerson: You should add that as an answer for future readers instead of leaving it as a comment.